# Aptana sqlite3 and bundler cannot install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite, aptana3

The problem is i cannot deploy my project in Heroku because it's asking for uninstall gem, etc..

i installed ruby on rails following this link: http://railsinstaller.org/

```
$ruby -v    
ruby 1.9.3p429 (2013-05-15) [i386-mingw32]

$gem -v    
2.0.3

$rails -v    
`C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:296:in
uld not find 'railties' (>= 0) among 12 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadErr
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependen
to_spec'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext
:47:in `gem'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'`
```

i don't know why rails became like this when yesterday it shows the version correctly.

then i used the deployment wizard in Aptana Studio 3
which shows this result

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 69, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (58/58), done.
Writing objects: 100% (69/69), 35.36 KiB, done.
Total 69 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Ruby/Rails app detected
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
-----> Installing dependencies using Bundler version 1.3.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle -
-binstubs vendor/bundle/bin
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.7)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.13)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.13)
       Installing mime-types (1.23)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.14)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.13)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (3.2.13)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Installing rails (3.2.13)
       Installing sass (3.2.9)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex
tension.
       /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (
the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You
 may
       need configuration options.
       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
       Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/bundle
/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

       Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
..
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
       Resolving dependencies...
       Installing rake (10.1.0)
       Installing i18n (0.6.1)
       Installing multi_json (1.7.7)
       Installing activesupport (3.2.13)
       Installing builder (3.0.4)
       Installing activemodel (3.2.13)
       Installing erubis (2.7.0)
       Installing journey (1.0.4)
       Installing rack (1.4.5)
       Installing rack-cache (1.2)
       Installing rack-test (0.6.2)
       Installing hike (1.2.3)
       Installing tilt (1.4.1)
       Installing sprockets (2.2.2)
       Installing actionpack (3.2.13)
       Installing mime-types (1.23)
       Installing polyglot (0.3.3)
       Installing treetop (1.4.14)
       Installing mail (2.5.4)
       Installing actionmailer (3.2.13)
       Installing arel (3.0.2)
       Installing tzinfo (0.3.37)
       Installing activerecord (3.2.13)
       Installing activeresource (3.2.13)
       Using bundler (1.3.2)
       Installing coffee-script-source (1.6.3)
       Installing execjs (1.4.0)
       Installing coffee-script (2.2.0)
       Installing rack-ssl (1.3.3)
       Installing json (1.8.0)
       Installing rdoc (3.12.2)
       Installing thor (0.18.1)
       Installing railties (3.2.13)
       Installing coffee-rails (3.2.2)
       Installing jquery-rails (3.0.4)
       Installing rails (3.2.13)
       Installing sass (3.2.9)
       Installing sass-rails (3.2.6)
       Installing sqlite3 (1.3.7)
       Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native ex
tension.

       /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
       checking for sqlite3.h... no
       sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal'
       or 'yum install sqlite-devel' and check your shared library search path (
the
       location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
       *** extconf.rb failed ***
       Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
       libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You
 may
       need configuration options.

       Provided configuration options:
       --with-opt-dir
       --without-opt-dir
       --with-opt-include
       --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
       --with-opt-lib
       --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
       --with-make-prog
       --without-make-prog
       --srcdir=.
       --curdir
       --ruby=/tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
       --with-sqlite3-dir
       --without-sqlite3-dir
       --with-sqlite3-include
       --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
       --with-sqlite3-lib
       --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
       --enable-local
       --disable-local
```

this is the error at the end

```
Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/bundle
/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.7 for inspection.
       Results logged to /tmp/build_3o7mrj90l1v27/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/
sqlite3-1.3.7/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
       An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.7), and Bundler cannot co
ntinue.
       Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.7'` succeeds before bundling.

 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
 !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/Rails app
```

i also tried this:

```
$ gem install sqlite3 -- --with-sqlite3-dir=/c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/sql
ite3
Successfully installed sqlite3-1.3.7-x86-mingw32
1 gem installed
```

and this:

```
$ gem install bundler
Fetching: bundler-1.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed bundler-1.3.5
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.3.5
1 gem installed
```

but i still get the same error. what could i've been doing wrong?

i am new to Ruby and Rails, and it's my first time deploying an app to heroku

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku uses `postgresql`. 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Remove `sqlite3` or move it into a `development` group in your Gemfile like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
```

remove `Gemfile.lock`
run `bundle install --without production`

```
git add .

git commit -am "bundle updating sqlite3"

git push heroku master
```

Comment: `$ gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]`
`sh: [:development,: No such file or directory`
sorry, got lost there

Comment: i searched the Gemfile and there was a lot, 
is it the Gemfile of the application?

Comment: i appended `group :development do...` to the Gemfile
and by remove is to delete?

Comment: you can comment it with # in front of gem 'sqlite3'. Then delete the Gemfile.lock and run again `bundle install --without production`.

Comment: this is what i got `Gemfile.lock required. Please check it in.`  `Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby/NoLockfile app`

Comment: my dear friend, on your local machine, go to your app root folder, find Gemfile, edit it as you see it in my answer. After this delete the Gemfile.lock file, run `bundle install --without production`, this will generate a new Gemfile.lock. After doing all this steps means you have changes in your app and you have to commit them, `git add .`, `git commit -am "bundle updating sqlite3"`, and only now you are ready to push to heroku `git push heroku master`

Comment: my mistake was i appended the development group on what was written by default on the Gemfile instead of overwriting it. Now i've done everything you said and it says that the app was deployed to heroku, but i don't see the program itself ? it only shows the Welcome to Rails.. sorry i'm really new to this.. Thanks a bunch

Comment: you should delete the public/index.html file and assign your controller as root in routes.rb file, lilke: `root :to => 'welcome#index'` where welcome is welcome_controller and index is the action.

Comment: any way, this is more than your question requests for, so for other issues you have you may want to open another questions so we don't write a rails development tutorial here in comments. Your main question has been answered I guess. ;) cheers